# Set column width dynamically according to content in table

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to replicate the default logic behind the  component from HTML in my react-native application, meaning that given the content of a cell it should expand its width accordingly and the set of cells in the same column and reduce the witdh of the other columns, something like this:

```
+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+
|  HEAD |  HEAD |            HEAD            |  HEAD |  HEAD |
+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+
| short | short | short                      | short | short |
+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+
| short | short | very long text in one cell | short | short |
+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+
| short | short | short                      | short | short |
+-------+-------+----------------------------+-------+-------+
```

And since at first I don't know the number of columns that the table is going to have I should only guarantee that the whole table will fit in the screen of the device (without horizontal scroll) and that each column will have a width to contain the contents of the longest string given by the dataset.

I've tried using the property `alignSelf: 'stretch'` in each cell but the result is not as expected as it only grows accordingly the content of that specific cell, like in the screenshot provided.

```
{data.map(d => {
    return (
        <View key={d} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', borderRightColor: 'red', borderRightWidth: 1, padding: 8 }}>
                <Text>{d}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', borderRightColor: 'red', borderRightWidth: 1, padding: 8 }}>
                <Text>{d}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', borderRightColor: 'red', borderRightWidth: 1, padding: 8 }}>
                <Text>{d}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', borderRightColor: 'red', borderRightWidth: 1, padding: 8 }}>
                <Text>{d}</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
})}
```

[image: Current status]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How about padding the text with spaces when the length of the string shorter than the maximal width?